# Possible to Extract CSR from PEM?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to extract a CSR (certificate signing request) from a PEM formatted file using openssl or another tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is impossible to extract original request from issued certificate, because certificate do not contain such information.

Comment: That's what I thought, but figured I'd make sure before generating a new CSR & certificate, thanks!